# Asp.net Localization doesn't work with MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have read a lot of articles about this but i can't it. When my aspx page is without masterpage, localization works normally. However, when my aspx page is with masterpage, localization doesn't work.

aspx page codes

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    GeneralHelper.GeneralHelperC.SetCulture();
    String selectedLanguage = GeneralHelperC.GetCulture();
    UICulture = selectedLanguage;
    Culture = selectedLanguage;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
        CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);

    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Comment: can you add a few more details? what content is not getting localized? just what is inside the master page or the entire page? how are you implementing localization? through resx files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it looks my fault. I created resx file with "Generate Local Resource" after than i changed resource file name Default.aspx.resx to Default.aspx.en.resx but it looks fault. can't change to default name.